# Drools KnowledgeBase size

Tags: java, drools, heap-memory, business-rules, rule-engine

What is the best way to calculate (without serialisation) the amount of heap memory in bytes that a Drools KnolwedgeBase will occupy?

Answer (score 0):

I'm interested to know why do you need to know that?
The knowledge base size is related with the number of Knowledge Packages that you are planning to add to it, so it really depends on the things that you are planning to do in your rules or processes.
Cheers

Comment: I have no processes, i have 1 package per knowledgebase. This package has a variable number of rules, anything ranging from several to several hundred rules. 

The reason i need to know is because i am storing lots of  knowledgebases inside a cache. I have an eviction process that starts to destroy entries when the cache reaches a certain size in memory.